# How to access instance variables in typescript file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript

I am trying to create a app in Rails with typescript. Now stuck in how to access my instance variables in typescript.

Comment: There are a few patterns you can follow. As Steve mentioned, you can output your instance variable as a data value embedded in your HTML and then use your JS/TypeScript to get the value. The gon gem tries to solve this problem. Lastly, you can use ajax with a callback/endpoint that yields the value(s) you need (my preference)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access rails data you can do it by writing the data in a div with an id and then using standard javascript in your typescript file...

```
<div id="my-name" ><%= @customer.name %></div>

var myName = document.getElementById("my-name").innerHTML;
```